# Angular5 bind and update instance in child component

Tags: angular, data-binding, binding, angular5

I have some trouble updating an object instance on a child component. Here's the object class:

```
class MyObject {
    elementList : Array<any> = [
        { id: 1, text: "Hello world"}
    ];
}
```

The main component:

```
export class PageComponent implements ... {
    myObject: any = new MyObject();

    constructor(...) {}

    reload() {
        this.getDataFromAPI.subscribe(data => {
            this.myObject.elementsList = data;
        });
    }
}
```

Main component template:

```
<div>
    <child-component [list]="myObject"></child-component>
</div>
```

Child component:

```
export class ChildComponent implements OnChanges, ... {
    @Input list: any;

    constructor(...) {}

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
        if (changes.list) {
            this.list = changes.list.currentValue;
        }
    }
}
```

And the child component template shows a list of elements in myObject.elementsList.

If i try to push/change elements in elementsList from the PageController they don't update in the child (but if i implement all the code in the PageController it works great). I found that if i substitute the entire instance in the PageController with a new one, it updates also the child, but i want to know is there is a better way to achieve this.

I'd like not to re-instantiate the object every time i need to refresh my list. How can i update the instance data and reflect it to the child?

Answer (score 0):

Angular will automatically update your property "list". You dont need to call ngOnChanges lifeciclehook